# sql [postgres] window function how to create column with last project date?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

i'm knew with window function

I have two tables which i join together (One user could have many project). Each Project has their own date (date_project)

I need query all users with thier projects and  add a column in the end which contain information about `last project date`(last project date==ordered by date_project DESC) which i believe must be compute by window function.

How can i achieve this?

Expected result

```
|id|date_project|user_id(FK)|user.name|last_project|
|  |            |           |         |            |
```

Table User

```
|id | name
|   |
```

Table Project

```
|id|date_project|user_id(FK)|
|  |            |           |
```

Comment: You can also use `last_value()`. You should explicitly specify an unbounded window frame because  by default  it contains the rows from the start of the partition to the current row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t_project.id
      ,date_project
      ,"user_id(FK)"
      ,name                                                                                   as "user.name"      
      ,first_value(date_project) over (partition by "user_id(FK)" order by date_project desc) as last_project
      
from t_project join t_user on t_user.id = t_project."user_id(FK)"
```

| id | date_project | user_id(FK) | user.name | last_project |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2022-04-23 | 1 | alma | 2022-04-23 |
| 1 | 2022-02-23 | 1 | alma | 2022-04-23 |
| 2 | 2022-03-23 | 2 | luna | 2022-03-23 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c930ec2ff150bffc5538e6367a6d65af)

Answer (score 0):

```
    select p.*, u.name, 
    first_value(date_project) over (partition by u.id order by date_project desc) 
as last_project_date
    from users u inner join projects p on u.id=p.user_id;
```